# Multiple supports inheritance in Java

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

Well Java does not support multiple inheritance in java..
But wait in eclipse we can see any class extends OBJECT  class by default, we can see all methods of Object class if we try to add unimplemented methods.

Now MY POINT IS i can make my class extend any class for example Thread.
So now my class extends Thread by user defined side and Object by default...
that  means multiple class inheritance ?

Comment: Nope. `YourClass <- Thread <- Object`. Single inheritance (which just means a class can only have one *direct* super-class).

Comment: The `Object` class is always at top of the inheritance hierarchy, in this situation creating a chain of classes - multilevel inheritance.

Comment: 1. You cannot extend 'final' classes in Java. 2. I would advise checking the definition of multiple inheritance in languages like C++.

Comment: There are so many versions of this question [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17897244/1037210), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17505030/1037210), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8470535/1037210), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4452461/1037210)...

Comment: So everyone is saying,,,if i dont use extends my class will inherit Object class directly,,else if i refer Thread class it will leave ,and maintain the prior definition via Threads to Object... ryt!

Answer (score 1):

Behavior similar to multiple inheritance can be seen with Java interfaces:

```
// implements BOTH Runnable AND ActionListener

public class MultipleInterfaces implements Runnable, ActionListener {
    @Override public void run() {}
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
}
```

Multiple inheritance would be like this:

```
// Not allowed, complete nuts

public class Amalgam extends ArrayList<Thread>, JPanel, Font {
    public Amalgam() {
        super(); // <- and what would this do?
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks for the info. Since you mentioned Runnable. Leme ask why does Thread class implements Runnable. Isnt Thread supposed to be having its own definition for run ? sorry if the Q was lame :)

Comment: It is actually a reasonable question. The way it's supposed to be, Thread is itself a runnable that runs a runnable that you hand in to the constructor. `new Thread(new Runnable() @Override public void run() {}).start();` See _"Defining and Starting a Thread"_: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html The other way you can look at it is Thread is a runnable with some extra features. You can extend Thread and override `run`. But technically it is "better" to do it the first way.

Answer (score 1):

A class can only have one superclass i.e. in java one class can only extend one class. If one is not specified, then it is implicitly extends to `Object`.

So suppose the class is  `MyClass` and it extends `MySuperClass`. As `MyClass` extends `MySuperClass` so it will not extend  directly `Object`. But `MySuperClass` class itself is not explicitly extending any class so it extends `Object` and in turn `MyClass` also extends `Object` in the hierarchy.

So it is not **Multiple inheritance** rather it is **Multilevel inheritance**. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior mentioned by you is multi-level inheritance which java supports by default

Answer (score 0):

This is **MultiLevel** inheritance and **not Multiple** inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

> **any** class extends OBJECT class by default

That means **Thead** class extends Object too.